# Eclipse not able to select Hybrid Mobile Engine Windows Universal (WUP) for Hybrid Cordova application

Tags: mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, eclipse-neon, jboss-tools

I'm using eclipse neon.1 + jboss tools 4.4.3.
When access "Select Hybrid Mobile Engine" preference menu option, I click "Download" and choose any Windows Universal engine. The installation occurs, but the engine isn't showed to select on dialog.

Can anyone help me?

PS: I have success installing android Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss Tools 4.4.3 requires Neon.2. You might need to update to the latest to make it work.

Or, if you want to use Neon.3, we have 4.4.4.AM3 available (.Final will be out in 3 weeks).

Downloads: http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/

Schedule: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBIDE?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page&status=released-unreleased